# How to disable the mandatory command windows when compiling solution in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, command

It will mandatory popup command window when I compile solution in VS2017. Some output info create in command window. The command window will close automatic when completing compile.

It go so fast I can't get its contents. So I missed some output info to check the error. On the other hand, if there are many projects in solution, the command window will popup when compiling each project. It will get my focus when popuping. I will be interrupt when doing other things.

It's awful. How can I disable the command window and show all compile info in output window? BTW, all my projects properties -> linker -> System->  sub-system had changed to Windows.

Comment: If I remember right VS creates log files in the directories for intermediate files. You may have a look into them. I wouldn't wonder if you find the missing output there.

Comment: You can use Process Monitor to log all executed processes during a compilation and then find out the offending command window parameters. It can help investigate why it is opened.

Comment: @Scheff I had checked log files in my debug directories. It doesn't help. I'm not only want the missing output. The popuping command windows occupy my focus every time! It sucks! Still thanks your reply.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Thanks for your suggestion. Although I don't know why, but the offending situation gone when I run VS2017 as administrator.